# IE7 Problem with position: fixed or Float?

Tags: css, html

This is a very simple layout, and the menu and navigation are suppose to stay fixed to the left, use any modern browser appart from IE to see how its suppose to look.
IE7 seems to fix the div's but pushes there position to the right, im not sure if this is a Position: fixed problem, or a float problem, or something else...

http://snapclicker.com/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, gods
if given `position:fixed` .so, there is no need to given float .Basically define position attributes.
try this:

```
position:fixed;
top:0px;
left:0px;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with `position: fixed`.

@sandeep has the right idea (explicitly define `top` and `left`), but I'm going to add specifics, because I *just* found them.

- To `#header`, add `left: 5px` and `top: 5px`.
- To `#nav`, add `left: 5px` and `top: 151px`. Remove the `margin-top` rule.

Answer (score 0):

both sandeep and thirtydot are right.. to avoid re-calculating position though.. wrap the left column (both the fixed divs) in a div and float it at 233px width, then add position: relative to it too - also remove the floats from the fixed divs, they aren't doing anything

```
#sidebar  {
 float: left;
 width: 233px;
 position: relative;
}
```

the your existing fixed divs should still work and you can change the padding (on the #container) without re-calculating